# Can I trigger PiP (picture-in-picture) in Google TV from a command?

Tags: google-tv

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the Picture-in-picture function in Google TV from a software command rather than from the button on the remote. As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the API to currently let me do this. So, 2 questions:

1. Has anyone tried a hack to make this happen? If so, could you share?
2. Does anyone know if Google is planning on adding this to the API?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't.  No plans.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Les. Though I know you have bigger things on your plate, is there an official place to put requests in for consideration on the future roadmap? Cheers.

Comment: developers.google.com/tv/  click on Issue Tracker at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger PIP using Anymote from a mobile device.

Comment: Thanks, Leon. That's another route I'm investigating, but somehow, I'd love to figure out if I could send a signal from the GTV box back to itself in order to bridge the gap between the general app environment and the Anymote environment, mostly because it's one less app the user has to install on one less device. Any tips on that?

Comment: Sorry, no. Anymote was specifically designed as a remote control protocol. It always requires another device to work.